# Drive a 3 W LED with a 18650 Li-ion battery

Tags: power, led, lithium-ion

I'm going crazy trying to figure out if there is an easy way to power a single 3 W LED (3 W - Forward Voltage: DC 3.2-3.4 V - Forward Current: 500-700 mA) with a single 18650 Li-ion battery.

```
Minimum Capacity: 2250mAh (0.54A discharge at 20°C)
Typical Capacity: 2100mAh (0.54A discharge at 20°C)
Nominal Voltage: 3.6V
Discharge End Voltage: 2.5V
Standard Charging Current: 1.1A
Charging Voltage: 4.20±0.03V
Standard Charging Time: 4.0hours
Max. Continuous Discharging Current: 2.2A
Internal Resistance: less than 35mΩ
Weight: less than 47.0g
```

Is there anyway to do this without using a DC/DC buck converter?

I'm trying to change an LED on a torch, so I don't have much space to work in.

Comment: can you make a heatsink?

Comment: Is it a single led or a string?

Comment: It's a single 3w led, and I have already a small heatsink on the torch, and one pcb heatsink on the led

Comment: You can achieve that by using a simple current limit resistor of require wattage between battery and led, but the brightness of the led will decay with the voltage of battery and you cannot use the battery to its maximum capacity... is it ok?

Comment: I already tried with 1ohm, 1,2 ohm, but the led is not powering up. Am I doing wrong calculations?

Comment: I think it is due to low voltage..First charge the battery to its full capacity. so that it will reach 4.2V. can you check the voltage?

Comment: I tought it might be that problem, but I tryed different batteries. Now I will charge them to full capacity and try again later.

Comment: If you put 100 Ohms to 5V to LED measure the voltage of LED ~ 50mA and verify it works.  Then measure battery. It must be 3.7min. Then report results in question.

Comment: If you're trying to cram stuff into a tight flashlight body, check how much longer the springs are than they need to be.  You can often gain 7-10mm by allowing the springs to compress more.  Also note that there are many premade LED drivers with drop in circular control boards to go behind the LED or drivers that can be made to fit into an endcap.

Comment: Buck and boost drivers are available, but for high power low or moderate price flashlights most people use LDO regulators with 7135 chips on them. Each 7135 chip passes 350mA, and you can parallel them.  The LED and battery are chosen so that the battery's voltage under load is close to the LED forward voltage so that the LDOs have little voltage drop and decent efficiency. A common mod is to solder 7135s over the existing ones, so if you want 2A, and there were no boards with 6 7135s, you would order a board with 3 and solder extra ones over the old ones like hats.

Comment: Once you've figured out how much space you're taking up, if there is still a bit of room in the springs, a spring bypass is a popular and effective mod.  Fine stranded copper wire or solder wick is soldered directly to the tip of the spring and to the spring's contact on the board.  The springs are a weak point in the conduction path because by nature they are long and not made of copper, so the higher the power of your flashlight, the more this will help.

Comment: if you want an easy way, buy a flashlight module.

Answer (score 1):

A buck-boost regulator will give you constant brightness and constant current but involves more design.

A Thermal sensor that rises in resistance with temperature will work well with the right part.

I would choose a 350mA to 500mA PTC and attach it to the LED heatsink.
They are rated by Holding current and trip current is 2x but if also heated by LED, it will trip earlier depending on thermal design.

Given the wide variation in Ri (internal resistance) of the 3W LED from 3.2-3.4V @ some rated current like 500mA this is equivalent to Vf=2.8V + If * R1 for Ri = 0.8 to 1.2Ω  adding 0.5 Ω parts in series/parallel as battery drops in voltage then bypass.  Normally a 3W LED is Ri= 1/3 Ω.

Your specs may vary but it appears to be a 1W LED with 3W pulse capability.  2.6V is dim 2.8V is 10% max current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fURdoc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: a simpler alternative would be to just use a constant current regulator, there are many specificaly designed for this task

Comment: @diegogmx  which one do you recommend with say 50~150 mV dropout @ desired current?  I know it's just a current sense, Comparator and low RdsOn FET in a 4 pin IC

Comment: 10,000 Farads? Really? Oh, I think that is part of a model for the LiIon cell.